# JPA - Select only the foreign key without the referenced object

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys, javadb

I have two tables in my database. Table A has a foreign key reference on the primary key of table B. In java this leads to an entity class A with a class member of entity B. 
Now i want to do a simple

```sql
SELECT * FROM A
```

Using JPA i now have the following code to achieve that:

```java
CriteriaQuery cq;
EntityManager em;
...

cq.select(cq.from(A.class));
List<A<> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

This is exactly what i don`t want. Instead of fetching objects of type A containing foreign key objects B, i only want the foreign key of B. Not the whole object. So in the end i have a List of objects containing only the primitive data types of A plus the foreign key of B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result type should be what you fetch, assume it is Long

```
TypedQuery<Long> tq;
```

The query in JPQL allows you then reference entitys members like

```
tq = em.createQuery(" SELECT a.memberB.id FROM A a ", Long.class);
```

where `memberB` is the name of the member field holding instance of `B`

But to have `A`s having only the memberB.id it as bit more tricky.

I now assume that you do not want to touch the `A` like adding any fields to it. One option would be to make the `memberB` loaded lazy and do the following.

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> tq =
   em.createQuery(" SELECT A, a.memberB.id FROM A", Object[].class);        
List<Object[]> longs = tq.getResultList(); // so array having pairs A,memberB.id
```

Then there are also some examples in SO that require extra field to `A` to hold id for `B`.

With above mentioned and this solution there is still a problem namely if you are considering performance/memory because you ask this.

If you want to fetch `A` it will fetch `B`s unless set loaded lazy. However it is still not quaranteed that `B`s really are loade lazy. It is up to implementation how it is obeyed.

But if lazy loading is obeyd the looking at arrays index [1] will not trigger loading of `B`.

It can be also that without any mods peeking only `memberB.id` will not trigger full load but it only load for a reference to object so only the `id` is loaded.

On the other hand it can be that already the peek on JPQL query will trigger full load i am not sure about that.

If it is about optimization i would leave that burden to the JPA implementation.